# c++ dylib curiously not found by excel's 2011 VBA on mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, fortran, dylib

I mainly tried to mimic [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/384318) in an even simpler setting. No luck.

I wrote a simple fortran code :

```
      subroutine POWERTWO (n, nsquared)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: POWERTWO
      integer, intent(in) :: n
      integer, intent(out) :: nsquared
      nsquared = n*n
      return
      end subroutine POWERTWO
```

that I compiled with gfortran as follows :

```
gfortran -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp.f90 -o ./tmp.dylib
```

Note that my `gfortran` is configured as follows :

```
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-checking=release --with-gmp=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --with-isl=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14 --with-cloog=/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

In the same folder where the dylib is, I have an excel 2011 xslm spreadsheet, and in the VBA I put the following code :

```
Declare Function powertwo CDecl Lib "tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByVal nsquared As Long)

Function VBA_UDFPowerTwo(n As Long) As Long

    Dim res As Long
    res = 0
    Call powertwo(n, res)
    VBAUDFPowerTwo = res

End Function
```

Now, doing in cell A2 the formula `=VBA_UDFPowerTwo(A1)` gives me a `#VALUE!`. Same result if I put the whole path to the dylib in the VBA as :

```
Declare Function powertwo CDecl Lib "/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/GITHUBRepos/DYLIBS/MyFirstDylib/tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByVal nsquared As Long)
```

or as

```
Declare Function powertwo CDecl Lib "Mackintosh HD:Users:XXXXXX:Documents:GITHUBRepos:DYLIBS:MyFirstDylib:tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByVal nsquared As Long)
```

and same if I replace `ByVal` by `ByRef`. Even a

```
Declare Function powertwo CDecl Lib "Mackintosh HD:Users:ludwigvonmises:Documents:GITHUBRepos:DYLIBS:MyFirstDylibt:tmp.dylib" Alias "POWERTWO" (n As Long, ByRef nsquared As Long)
```

did not make my day. Am I missing something or doing something wrong ?

I did a `nm` on the dylib an get the following :

```
00000fa4 t ___x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
00000f87 T _powertwo_
         U dyld_stub_binder
```

whereas `nm -gU` gives me :

```
00000f87 T _powertwo_
```

Console.app told me the following while excel was opened and calculation in the A2 cell triggered :

```
22/08/15 19:37:32,892 Microsoft Excel[2971]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.5 instead of 10.10.5. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
22/08/15 19:37:32,892 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x96a01291 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x92c4f0b5 dispatch_once_f + 251
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x92c500d8 dispatch_once + 31
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x9697a69d _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1050
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x969797c0 Gestalt + 150
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 5   MicrosoftComponentPlugin            0x01bdb27e McpInitLibrary_ + 505
22/08/15 19:37:32,893 Microsoft Excel[2971]: 6   MicrosoftComponentPlugin            0x01bdb0ae McpInitLibrary_ + 41
```

and `otool -L tmp.dylib` showed the following :

```
./tmp.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/lib/i386/libgfortran.3.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/lib/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

**EDIT**

Resorting to :

```
Declare Function powertwo_ CDecl Lib "Macintosh HD:Users:XXXXXX:Documents:GITHUBRepos:DYLIBS:MyFirstDylib:tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByRef nsquared As Long)
```

as [Ken Thomases](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312143/ken-thomases) suggested, made excel crash when calculation triggered in cell A2, which shows at least that the exported function name is not `powertwo` but `powertwo_`, and that excel's VBA loads tmp.dylib indeed.

Comment: Is Excel writing anything to the console log when it tries to load your plug-in? You can check with /Applications/Utilities/Console.app. What does `otool -L tmp.dylib` show? I suspect it has a dependency on a library which is not in the standard search path (see the [dyld(1) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)).

Comment: @KenThomases Thx for your interest in such a microlocalized subject ! I added the output of Console.app (never used it before so I may have done the wrong thing) and of `otool -L tmp.dylib` at the end of my question for you to see. By the way I do not load any plugin, I just wrote a .f90 file I compiled in a .dylib, as I describe in my question.

Comment: Hmm. The console output is probably benign and not related to the plug-in apparently not working. You can examine the Excel process after trying to use your plug-in using `vmmap -w -interleaved <pid of Excel>` to see if `tmp.dylib` has been successfully loaded into the process. I notice that the `nm` output has an underscore both prefixed and suffixed to `_powertwo_`. The prefix is normal for C symbols and, for example, `dlsym()` would handle it. The suffix seems unusual. Does it work to `Declare Function powertwo_ …`?

Comment: Most of the Fortran people here don't check all version and compiler tags (`fortran90`, `gfortran`, etc...) - you should consider tagging `fortran` instead of `gcc5` or `gfortran`. See this for more info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261912/fortran-language-tag-use.

Comment: @Ross Done. Even if I am not completely sure the problem is fortran related. Anyway.

Comment: @KenThomases Ok, I tried this : `Declare Function powertwo_ CDecl Lib "Macintosh HD:Users:XXXXXX:Documents:GITHUBRepos:DYLIBS:MyFirstDylib:tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByRef nsquared As Long)` which made my excel crash. I guess that powertwo_ is the right exported function name. (Aything else provokes a `#VALUE!`) But why the crash ?...

Comment: You'll need to show the crash report for me to have any chance of guessing. I guess either the calling convention (`cdecl`) is wrong or `ByRef` isn't right. (I don't know VBA, fortran, or the Microsoft plug-in model, so I'm completely stabbing in the dark.) It might also be necessary to see the disassembly of `tmp.dylib`, which you can get using `otool -tV` on it.

Comment: @KenThomases I'm in the middle of putting the output of `vmmap -w -interleaved` in a gist for you to see, even it it has no reference at all to tmp.dylib or tmp. Will do the same for `otool -tV` and the crash report. Question : how do I get this crash report ?...

Comment: @KenThomases the 'vmmap -w -interleaved' gist : https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/5a7b28a2b663456ac4ca
The gist containing the disassembly of tmp.dylib is here : https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/b8b526897da0421f3033

Comment: The crash report should be in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports. The `vmmap` was only to determine if Excel was loading your library. I think you've confirmed that by making it crash. Also, when it crashes, there might be useful information logged to the console log.

Comment: @KenThomases Yeah sorry obviously. The crash report from excel application is here : https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/8e67876d35697e206090
Nothing concerning 22/08/2015 or excel in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

Comment: @KenThomases The console reported this : https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/9d50af666da43caf8382

Comment: @KenThomases Finally, is also have crash with `ByVal`

Comment: Hum, gave a shot to `stdcall` instead of `DLLEXPORT`, same result.

Comment: According to some searching, Fortran subroutines always take arguments by reference. So, try declaring it in VBA with both arguments `ByRef`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, forgot to mention that I tried this already, with the same result as before...

Comment: I would like to `lldb tmp.dylib` but I don't know how run excel in lldg session, as ` r "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Excel"` says "failed to launch or debug process"

Comment: Apparently, from the console output you posted earlier, Excel is running the plug-in in an XPC service (helper process). That's going to make it difficult to debug. If you can manage to get it loaded but not crashing, you might be able to find the process and attach to it (`lldb -p <pid>`). Perhaps add another function to `tmp.dylib` that does nothing and a VBA function which uses that. Hopefully, that won't crash. Then, you can attach the debugger and use the crashing function.

Comment: Funniest thing in the world : to use a dylib function doing nothing, you should wrap with a `Declare Function`etc, and use this vba wrapper function in excel... which makes it crash... ;-) I will try to find the process "manually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at doing this had a few issues:

- mismatch in the procedure arguments

  Fortran passes by reference by default, as does VBA.  In your multiple attempts at getting the interface right you didn't quite match them up.
- mismatch in the procedure return value

  Your Fortran procedure is a subroutine, which returns no value.  You need to declare the VBA procedure as a `Sub`, not a `Function`.
- Use of Intel Fortran directives

  The `!DEC$` directives (afaik) are just comments to gfortran and not interpreted.

---

Here is what I've done, and tested that it works.  The Fortran has been re-written using the `iso_c_binding` C-interop features of Fortran 2003 to give more control over the exported procedure interface and ensure that you get what you want.  You are using a modern Fortran compiler, so this is not an issue for you.

The Fortran:

```
subroutine POWERTWO (n, nsquared) bind(C, name='powertwo')
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_long
  implicit none
  integer(kind=c_long), intent(in) :: n
  integer(kind=c_long), intent(out) :: nsquared
  nsquared = n*n
  return
end subroutine POWERTWO
```

This will produce an procedure with the C interface

```
void powertwo(long int* n, long int* squared)
```

I compiled this with gfortran 5.2 (from macports):

```
gfortran-mp-5 -m32 -dynamiclib -o test32.dylib test.f90
```

In Excel VBA, I have declared the procedure as:

```
Declare Sub powertwo CDecl Lib "/Users/casey/code/so/xlstest/test32.dylib" (ByRef n As Long, ByRef nsquared As Long)

Function VBA_UDFPowerTwo(n As Long) As Long

    Dim res As Long
    res = 0
    Call powertwo(n, res)
    VBA_UDFPowerTwo = res

End Function
```

Note the above also fixes a typo in your line `VBAUDFPowerTwo = res`, which is missing an underscore after VBA (doesn't match the Function name).  I have also changed the imported function to be a `Sub` and explicitely declared its arguments as `ByRef` (which should be the default).

This produces the desired behavior:

[image]

Comment: WIth which flags do I compile this ? I guess that `-m32`should be replaced by `-arch i386` that also works with ifort, but what for `-dynamiclib` ?

Comment: Ok, same result, it makes excel crash.

Comment: With the fortran code you advised me to use, yes. And with this declaration : `Declare Function powertwo CDecl Lib "Macintosh HD:Users:XXXXXX:Documents:GITHUBRepos:DYLIBS:MyFirstDylib:tmp.dylib" (n As Long, ByRef nsquared As Long)` Dropping out the `CDecl` gives the same result. The function is called as follows :

`Function VBA_UDFPowerTwo(n As Long) As Long`

    `Dim res As Long`

    `res = 0`

    `Call powertwo(n, res)`

    `VBAUDFPowerTwo = res`

`End Function`

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try this on your mac ?

Comment: @user10000100_u I have edited to include a complete, tested example that fixes your problems.  Please take a look at it.

Comment: Ok, your exemple made my day, but : if in the VBA I put `ByRef n` then the calc works and doesn't make excel crash anymore, but throws "random" values, 301299968, 1502609408, 557858816 etc, that are adresses for sure. If I put `ByVal n`, then vbA_UDFPowerTwo works as intended. On this note, how would you proceed to debug the `ByRef n` case, to look at what is passed by fortran etc ? In windows, and with c++ and not fortran, I attached the excel embarking my dll put break point in the c++, trigger calc in excel, and it breaks in c++ code etc. Can I do this with `lldb` here also ?

Comment: @user10000100_u you might have still been using my last example that declared `n` in Fortran with the `value` attribute.  You can mix and match each argument as necessary, but in Fortran if you use `value`, the VBA should be `ByVal` and if you don't use `value`, then the VBA should be `ByRef`.

Comment: No, I haven't, double checked. Btw, I tried after to include two subroutines in the fortran file, and `nm` showed to me only one function. Is this fortran related or ?

Comment: Btw, Imagine I have an old fortran compiler. Would this be doable with f77 ? If so, how ?

Comment: @user10000100_u if you were limited to standard FORTRAN77, you would use your original code (in the Q) without the `!DEC$` line.  For the VBA you'd use `powertwo_` for the procedure name and `ByRef` for the arguments.  You would still use `Sub` in the VBA since it is a subroutine and not a function.

Comment: so the last thing I do not understand is the byref/byval "issue", as I said, I have double-checked and copy pasted your fortran and vba codes, and only changes path.

Comment: @user10000100_u I don't have an explanation for that.  I describe how it should work (and that is how it works for me), but I don't know why you are seeing different behavior.

Comment: Could almost be an x-file case ;-) Thx for your answer anyway. Validated. (Btw, no clue for debugging excel ?)

Comment: @user10000100_u No idea on the excel debugging, sorry.

Comment: What would be the syntax to export a function and not a subroutine, to be able to write `res=VBA_UDFPowerTwo(n)` in VBA ?

Comment: Ok, got it alone. ;-)